# Use class in same package in Java in Ubuntu

Tags: java, class, compilation, package

I am using Ubuntu. I have created a package p1 with classes A and B. On desktop, I have created a directory named p1 for this sake.

```
-------
A.java
-------
package p1;

class A {...}

-------
B.java
-------
package p1;

class B {

 A obj = new A();

 ...

}
```

Compiling above:

```
javac A.java ----> creates A.class without any error

javac B.java -----> cannot find symbol A
```

Am I not compiling it properly?

Answer (score 1):

The command you should use is

```
javac A.java B.java
```

I urge you learn about [apache ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [apache maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [Scala Build Tool](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) (sbt) and/or [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) if you want to know how to compile more complex software. Ant and maven are very popular, with sbt and gradle being relatively newer (and more "exciting").

Comment: if we don't specify the classpath, will it not the current directory be added to classpath by default?